# CSV to Mysql import to match fields

Tags: mysql, csv, import-from-csv

Is there such a way of importing data from a CSV into mysql that can match a field and will just update values in rows? Hope I have explained myself clearly enough!

**Example:**
ID   Name
1    x
2    y
3    z

I want to replace names for matched ID's from the csv file to mysql.
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a loading tool called `LOAD DATA`, but as the name implies, it basically just loads CSV data into a table.  You may load the above data into some table, e.g. `names`, and then use the following update query:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN names t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
SET t1.name = t2.name;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why this answer received a downvote when the question was left untouched?